# Correct terms and words for sections and parts of selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, terminology

What is the correct term for the sections of CSS selectors that are **separated by commas**?

```css
    body.foo .login , body.bar .login { ... }
/*                  |
           Part 1   |  Part 2         */
```

Within those sections, what is the term for the parts **separated by combinators** (spaces, `+`, `>`, etc)?

```css
    body.foo .login , ... { ... }
/*          |
   Part 1   |   Part 2    */
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What is the correct term for the sections of CSS selectors that are **separated by commas**?

These are called [**complex selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4#complex). The entire comma-separated list is known as a **selector-list**.

> Within those sections, what is the term for the parts **separated by combinators** (spaces, `+`, `>`, etc)?

These are known as [**compound selectors**](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4#compound).

So, a selector-list is made up of one or more complex selectors separated by commas, and each complex selector is made up of two main parts: compound selectors, and combinators. It can also optionally contain pseudo-elements.

Compound selectors used to have the rather convoluted name "sequence of simple selectors". Worse still, complex selectors were just called "selectors". Needless to say, I recommend using the new terms as they are much more straightforward, much less cumbersome and completely unambiguous compared to their predecessors.

---

And since I'm here, here are the rest of the definitions...

- A **simple selector** is one fundamental component of selectors. It is any one of the following:

  - Universal selector (`*`), [optionally with a namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#univnmsp)
  - Type selector (`a`, `div`, `span`, `ul`, `li`, etc), [optionally with a namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#typenmsp)
  - Attribute selector (`[att]`, `[att=val]`, etc), [optionally with a namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attrnmsp)
  - Class selector (`.class`)
  - ID selector (`#id`)
  - Pseudo-class (`:pseudo-class`)
- As answered above, a **compound selector** (formerly a "sequence of simple selectors") is a chain of simple selectors not separated by a combinator:

  ```
  a:not([rel="external"]):hover
  ```
- A **combinator** is another fundamental component of selectors. It is a symbol or token that separates two compound selectors, establishing in its place a relationship between the two elements represented by the two compound selectors. There are currently four combinators in use today:

  - Descendant combinator:

    ```
    article p
    ```
  - Child combinator:

    ```
    /* 
     * The extra spaces in between are whitespace,
     * and are therefore insignificant.
     */
    ul > li
    ```
  - Adjacent sibling combinator:

    ```
    header + section
    ```
  - General sibling combinator:

    ```
    h2 ~ p
    ```

  More combinators may be introduced in later specifications.
- And a **complex selector** (formerly just "selector") is a complete string made up of compound selectors linked by combinators:

  ```
  nav[role="main"] > ul:first-child > li
  ```
- The **subject** of a complex selector is its last, or only, compound selector, representing the element that will be matched or styled. In the above example, the subject of the selector is `li`.
- The term **selector** has been generalized, so it may now refer to *any of the following* for the purposes of simplicity and brevity, and which one it's referring to at any given moment should be gleaned from context:

  - Simple selector
  - Compound selector
  - Complex selector
  - Selector-list (e.g. the "selector" component of a style rule)

Some personal notes:

- The term "key selector" was coined by browser vendors for use with selector implementations, and is not an official term. It is often used to mean "subject of the selector" however, because implementations happen to use the subject of the selector as the key for the purposes of determining matches.
- The term "pseudo-selector" was coined by authors to mix pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements, and is not an official, or indeed meaningful, term. Although you can find it in some early-stage W3C CSS2/3 drafts, that was probably a mistake. [Please don't use this term](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111323/retagging-questions-with-the-pseudo-selector-tag), as it needlessly creates confusion by attempting to group two completely different concepts into a single umbrella term.
- Pseudo-elements (`::pseudo-element`) are not simple selectors, and therefore cannot appear in places where only actual elements may be matched. However, they are still considered selectors for the purposes of CSS parsing, and as stated above currently can appear at the end of any complex selector in a list (i.e. at the end of the last, or only, compound selector of each complex selector).
- In CSS, a typical style rule (formerly "ruleset") consists of a **selector** and a **declaration block**.
- Namespace prefixes are not selectors in their own right, but they may be applied to type selectors, universal selectors and attribute selectors to match components in a document that are (or are not) namespaced.
- The [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4#specificity) of a selector currently only refers to that of a single complex selector. When matching rules, any of the complex selectors in a list that match a given element will be considered for specificity calculations. If more than one complex selector matches an element, the most specific one will be used for calculations.

  Specificity will be a more complicated issue with some level 4 selectors, such as `:is()` and the enhanced `:not()`, and the `of S` notation in the enhanced `:nth-child()` pseudo.

Comment: This answer is so awesome that I crashed Safari on my iPhone at least once while writing it.

Comment: You are right: this _is_ awesome. Just one question: if a pseudo-element is a selector (and it is), why is it not a simple selector? I mean, a rule like `::first-letter {color:red}` works and makes lots of first letters red.

Comment: @Mr Lister: It's because pseudo-elements don't follow the same syntactic rules as simple selectors. See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements

Comment: @Mr Lister: Also, in your example rule, the universal selector is implied, so it's really `*::first-letter {color:red}`. So, you have a simple selector, and a pseudo-element.

Comment: I see you deleted most of the comments now, except mine where I said your answer was awesome. I learned from that. Anyway, if you follow the logic of your remark, then `.classname` wouldn't be a simple selector either, for the reason that it's short for `*.classname`.

Comment: @Mr Lister: No, being implied is a property of the universal selector alone, mentioned here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector Now since it has its own rules, perhaps it wouldn't be fair to count it as a simple selector either. In that case, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) offers terminology for this:

> A selector is a chain of one or more sequences of simple selectors separated by combinators. One pseudo-element may be appended to the last sequence of simple selectors in a selector.
>
> A sequence of simple selectors is a chain of simple selectors that are not separated by a combinator. It always begins with a type selector or a universal selector. No other type selector or universal selector is allowed in the sequence.
>
> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.
>
> Combinators are: whitespace, "greater-than sign" (U+003E, >), "plus sign" (U+002B, +) and "tilde" (U+007E, ~). White space may appear between a combinator and the simple selectors around it. Only the characters "space" (U+0020), "tab" (U+0009), "line feed" (U+000A), "carriage return" (U+000D), and "form feed" (U+000C) can occur in whitespace. Other space-like characters, such as "em-space" (U+2003) and "ideographic space" (U+3000), are never part of whitespace.

There are some small terminology differences between CSS 2 and 3

> the list of basic definitions (selector, group of selectors, simple selector, etc.) has been changed; in particular, what was referred to in CSS2 as a simple selector is now called a sequence of simple selectors, and the term "simple selector" is now used for the components of this sequence

Comment: so a "simple selector" would be `#login`, and a "sequence" would be `a#login.onsite`, right? How would you differentiate a selector like `.a, .b` from one like `.a`? Maybe `.a, .b` is a "selector" and `.a` is a "chain" (made up of a "sequence" with one "simple selector")?

Comment: @GGG: `.a, .b` is not "a selector", because it doesn't consist solely of simple selectors and combinators. The spec generally refers to something like `.a, .b` as a "group" or "group of selectors", but that's not a technical term in the same way that "selector" and "simple selector" and so on are.

Comment: A comma separated set seems to just be referred to as a "group of selectors"

Answer (score 1):

The parts separated by commas are called selectors.

Within a selector we have simple_selectors and combinators.

See [the grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html).

Comment: aren't combinators the "operator-like" things including space that separate parts of the selector?

Comment: if the parts between the commas are selectors, what's the whole thing (`.a, .b`) called?

Comment: Yes, `+` and '>` are called combinators. The combinators appear between (separate) the _simple selectors_.  These at least are the terms used in the CSS grammar.  Whether people colloquially distinguish between selectors and simple selectors is not clear.

Comment: The whole thing doesn't really have a name.  Remember that something like `A,B` {x:y}` is actually syntactic sugar for `A{x:y} newline B{x:y}`.  The grammar shows that a *ruleset* is made up of one or more selectors separated by commas followed by one or more declarations separated by semicolons and delimited with curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, it helps to think of it as just being shorthand.