# Mark links as read with a hook

Tags: css

I would like to mark the links the already read with a hook. Unread links should not display the hook.
The [rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.SEC7115)) is the visited link, and can differ only in color.

Would it be the fine to put the hook of the unread link transparent?
Or is there a better solution?

```
a.readed {color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)}
a.readed:visited {color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)}

<a href=""> goto</a><a href="" class="readed"> ✓</a>
```

Comment: Did you try using `::after{ content: ' ✓'}` ?

Comment: The Hook should only dispalyed if the Link are readed (visited). Sorry i edit my question.

Comment: You should have a look at this : https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding additional link, just put it as CSS `content` of `:after`/`:before`

```css
a:after {
  content: '✓';
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<a>Some link</a>
```

Comment: The Hook should only displayed if the link are readed. The link himself should be allways visible.

Comment: a.visted:after {
  content: '✓';
  display: inline;
}
coud work and Looks smarter. I will tried.

Comment: oh it must a:visited:after but ist wrong how can i write that both together works?

Comment: i found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342516/combine-avisited-with-aafter-or-chaining-pseudo-classes-with-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like change the color of the link to see what already was clicked.

```css
a {
  color: blue;
}

a[tabindex]:focus:after {
 color: red;
 outline: none;
 content: 'insert hook here';
 display: inline;

}
```

```html
<a href="#" tabindex="1">Test</a>
```

But your way is also good so if it works it doesn't really matter I guess.

EDIT:

didnt answer your question. 
so i tried some things this is the closest i got to displaying the hook
only problem is after u click out range it hides again so fiddle arround with this.

Comment: You are right it is not a 100% solution. But it is only a "nice to have" and not importend for a process to display the marked hook. Like a Cookie solution are to much. Thx

Comment: No problem just do as you feel how it has to be done. it can be done in multiple ways.