# Is there a CSS selector for all grandchildren except first?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uerea13x/), how can I style all `<a>` elements except the first grandchild? (abc) with a single selector? I want to avoid using two rules at all costs.

```css
#outer a:not(:first-child){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="firstParent">
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>def</a>
    <a>hij</a>
  </div>
  <div id="secondParent">
    <a>klm</a>
    <a>opq</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this *(not sure if you can avoid more than 1 selector)*

```css
#outer >div:first-child a:not(:first-child),
#outer >div:not(:first-child) a{
  color: red;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="firstParent">
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>def</a>
    <a>hij</a>
  </div>
  <div id="secondParent">
    <a>klm</a>
    <a>opq</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If inheritance is an option then barro32's answer will suffice. If the requirement is to target only the a elements and not the div elements, then doing this with one selector requires level 4 :not() in the form of `#outer > div > a:not(:first-child > :first-child)`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/erxfbuj1) (requires Safari)

Comment: (In case that looks confusing to you: `#outer > div > a:not(div:first-child > a:first-child)`)

Comment: @BoltClock yes for sure the level 4 will bring more flexibility ... waiting to answer the first questions about them ;)

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14437502) a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983098) of [them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28050505) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28724566) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32580945) [joined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35993791) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36421262) [site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41455901), so I'll leave some of the rest to you. 6+ years after the FPWD, there are still barely any implementations so you're not that late to the party. Anyway, I did just get an idea for a Q&A for :not() that I think you'd appreciate.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm writing scss files - I was unable to paste either of the 2 formats and unable to replicate it with scss nesting :(
My editor complains about syntax error.

Comment: @user2651804: Sorry, I wasn't clear - those selectors are from a future standard and don't work today.

Comment: @BoltClock yes intresting posts, i never though i will find questions related to drafts and non-implemented features ... well am here since only 4 months so still discovering :) by the way any help with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777787/margin-collapsing-with-floated-element) ? .. i saw you had many posts about complex margin-collapsing situation, so maybe you have some clue :)

Answer (score 1):

***One rule*** 2 selectors:

**`a ~ a`** The *general sibling combinator* covers any `<a>` that follows another `<a>`. This basically selects all but the first `<a>` of sibling `<a>`.

**`div:nth-of-type(n+2) a`** This targets all `<a>` inside the second div ***and any preceding sibling divs in the future***.

### Demo

```css
a~a,
div:nth-of-type(n+2) a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="firstParent">
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>def</a>
    <a>hij</a>
  </div>
  <div id="secondParent">
    <a>klm</a>
    <a>opq</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Props to Temani Afif for suggesting `(n+2)`.

Comment: i would generalise the second selector to `2+n` for example so it covers all potential divs ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works, not exactly sure why!

```css
#outer :not(:first-child) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="firstParent">
    <a>abc</a>
    <a>def</a>
    <a>hij</a>
  </div>
  <div id="secondParent">
    <a>klm</a>
    <a>opq</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well you select everything but not the first child at any level :) ... so you add red to `seconParent` and thus it will apply to all his childs even if later you won't select his first a ;) ... so you apply red to all `a` except of `abc` and `klm` and you apply red to secondParent

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: but pay attention as this may not always behave as excepted ... add `border` to your style and see what happen :) with border it won't work like with color